# How to support TLS 1.2 for Xamarin Windows 8.1 and UWP platforms

Tags: xamarin, httpclient

The current official Xamarin website only supports iOS and Android:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/

The same goes for ModernHttpClient PCL (iOS/Android only)

So is there anyway we can support TLS 1.2 for Windows 8.1 and UWP platforms? If Yes, please share and provided tutorial with source code

I am using Profile 111 for my PCL

Many thanks!

Comment: Please avoid duplicate posts here and at the Xamarin forums https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90689/how-to-support-tls-1-2-for-windows-8-1-and-uwp-platforms

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin is meant to cover iOS, Android and Mac. As long as you are working on a Windows based platform, you're working with Microsoft .Net. This means, there is no need for any additional tooling and no Xamarin/Mono involved here. As of .Net 4.6 (or was it 4.5 - I don't remember 100% sure) you'll get TLS 1.2 support.

The above is also true if you are using Xamarin.Forms to run your apps on Windows (Phone) 8.x or UWP.

Comment: I have tried that. In VS 2015 whenever I change my target to .NET 4.6, it automatically set it back to 4.5. See the screenshot because they target the same set of APIs. I asked the same question in Xamarin forum here with attached screenshot. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/259170#Comment_259170